# How to uninstall R and RStudio with all packages, settings and everything else?

Tags: r, package, rstudio, uninstallation

*I messed up something and there is a problem with tidyverse. Tried to find a solution but spend lots of time without result.*

How to uninstall R and RStudio with all packages, settings and everything else on Windows. I tried to uninstall through Windows uninstall menu and after I installed R and RStudio again same packages appeared as they were installed before. How can I erase everything related to R and RStudio so I be able to make a fresh install?

Comment: What OS are you on? Packages might be installed in your local directory. maybe ``~/.R``.

Comment: @ZanCoul Windows 8.1

Comment: Open ``R`` or ``Rstudio`` and type ``.libPaths()`` this will show you where all the packages are installed. Just make sure that everything in those folders are deleted after you uninstall ``R``. Good luck.

Comment: Maybe not the best but maybe manually delete the folder containing the `libraries` and then unistall?

Comment: @ZanCoul That helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I have further issues with the previous answer. For that reason, I have extended the answer with further steps (which I experienced currently) as below:

1. Run `.libPaths()` and save the listed directories shown on the RStudio console. In my case, it looks like:

> ```
> .libPaths()
>
> "C:/Users/%USERNAME%/Documents/R/win-library/3.6" 
> "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.3/library"
> ```

2. Uninstall **R for Windows**, **RStudio** and **RTools** from Windows "*Programs and Features*" menu. You might navigate there through: *Add or remove programs* > *App & features* > *On search box*
3. Delete everything in folders that was shown after running `.libPaths()` instruction in R to know where R packages are installed.

Therefore, I have manually deleted following files and folders (they remain there after full uninstallation of R, RStudio and RTools) as well:

> ```
> C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\R\
> C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\.Rhistory
> C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp > only specific ones mentioned below.
> ```

Specific ones can be various files and folders which can be deleted under this directory related with R and RStudio sessions. In my case, `Rtmpcx1qAZ`, `Rtmpk7UXWj`, `Rscript3d2438240e1`, ... are only example files or folder names to give you rough idea.

4. Delete everything inside those listed folders or completely delete those listed folders as well:

> ```
> C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\R
> C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\rstudio
> C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\RStudio-Desktop
> C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\r-miniconda
> C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\r-reticulate
> C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\??? (!!!might be some others in your case!!!)
> C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\R
> C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\RStudio
> ```

Then you can move on the **re-installation** side for R as below (after suggested reboot of Windows). In order (please):
Download [R for Windows](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/), (download [RTools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) if you need) and [RStudio Desktop](https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/#download).

- Install R ([R for Windows](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/))
- Install [RTools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) (if you need)
- Install RStudio ([RStudio Desktop](https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/#download))

Comment: Worked for me! Tidyverse works fine now. I updated to R 4.0.3 and also had problems with tidyverse that I could not fix even after long searches. Then I tried to reinstall tidyverse in the shell and it was fine.

Answer (score 9):

1. Run `.libPaths()` and save the two directories shown on the console
2. Uninstall R and RStudio from Windows "Programs and Features" menu.
3. Delete everything in folders that was shown after running `.libPaths()` in R.
4. Delete everything in `c:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\RStudio-Desktop\`
5. Install R and after Rstudio.

All packages where deleted and I think all Rstudio settings too.

Comment: How about the packages under C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp ? In my case, there are various folders which might had previously generated through rstudio sessions. How can we know which ones are generated by rstudio and should delete them manually ?

Comment: Typo : "All packages WERE deleted"