# After removing RStudio and reinstalling-Site can't be reached

Tags: r, rstudio

I had to uninstall/remove and reinstall R. Somehow it affected also RStudio. Upon starting RStudio I got the message: site can't be reached, reload... I then removed RStudio and downloaded again. After the installation and starting it I am getting the same message. I repeated again the removal and the downloading. I still get the same window with that message.

Does somebody know how to fix this problem? It all happened because I needed the version 3.5 of R. Interestingly after so many times of downloading and installing R, each time I only get the previous version which I had, 3.4.4. Why? I downloaded it from CRAN.

Many thanks for a comment.

Comment: Not really sure what your error message represents.  But In RStudio under Tools -> Global Options you have to make sure that the R Version path is pointing to the location of the version you want to use.

Comment: The toolbar is not active. I can only see the toolbar, nothing else from the RStudio interface but toolbar is not operational.

Comment: I'm only guessing here.  But it could be that your registry is messed up.  Suggest uninstalling RStudio again then use a registry cleaner like ccleaner before a re-install.  Good luck.

Comment: If you would like to fully uninstall then clean reinstall R and RStudio, follow the steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61187094/1953250

Answer (score 0):

using macOS i had to upgrade to the latest version of R using homebrew

Answer (score 0):

On Win10, I had RStudio launching with a white page and no menu working at all (only titles of the menus). After re-installing RStudio, I had the message "Site can't be reached". But then I looked at the file `"/Program File/R/R-3.6.2"` where I could only see `/bin and /library repertory.` So re-installing R, the `/R-3.6.2` repertoire was full of 10 sub-repertoires and 7 files: RStudio was working properly.