# Rstuido Crash after changing graphic setting and no will not reopen even after reinstalling

Tags: r, rstudio

I found that `plotly` was not working in my version of r studio that I was running through a VDI, I was reading a forum post online and tried changing the rendering engine to 'Desktop OpenGL'. However, during restarting rstudio crashed, and no when I try to reopen it I just get the error 'RStudio has stopped working'.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling both RStudio and R but this has had no effect on the problem.

I have R version 3.5.3 and Rstudio 1.2.1335

Can anyone offer some advice on how to fix this?

Comment: Hi @Tom91, try deleting the RStudio profile directory --> https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-Desktop-s-State

Comment: @M.Viking Thanks for suggesting, that looks like it should work but unfortunately it hasn't.

Comment: :( . at the bottom of that link is an additional section on "Resetting Other Preferences". maybe?

Comment: RStudio has it's own support site at https://community.rstudio.com/

Comment: See also: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017886674-Troubleshooting-RStudio-Rendering-Errors

Comment: @M.Viking I had not spotted that, and it worked! Thank you for showing me the link.

Comment: If you would like to fully uninstall then clean reinstall R and RStudio, follow the steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61187094/1953250

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who runs into a similar problem as this, in order to reset the graphics settings, or any settings for that matter, you will need to delete the preferences folder.

On windows find this by via start --> Run and entering the command

```
%appdata%\RStudio
```

Once you have deleted this (or moved it somewhere to back it up) you can open RStudio, which will automatically create a new preferences folder.

Full information can be found [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-Desktop-s-State)