# RStudio crashes after installing "bigmemory" package

Tags: r, rstudio, ehcache-bigmemory

So i have installed the `bigmemory` package and it was working just fine. The next day i opened RStudio and it looks that it's trying to load the package without any command.

> Loading required package: bigmemory

It also pops an error:

> R encountered a fatal error. The session was terminated.

After pressing "Ok" (the only options) it pops another error:

> Javascript Alert: null

It looks that RStudio is not responding. I can't write anything on the console, can't open anything, can't see anything on the "Files/Plots/Packages/Help/Viewer" panel.

I can only open R and uninstall the packages through `remove.packeges("bigmemory")` and `remove.packeges("bigmemory.sri")` (or just delete the 2 files on the lib path) but when I open R again it's installing both packages by it self.

Specs:

- R version 3.6.1
- RStudio version 1.2.1335
- Windows 10

Comment: This reads like the workspace got saved and gets loaded when you start R. Delete that file.

Comment: If you would like to fully uninstall then clean reinstall R and RStudio, follow the steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61187094/1953250