# Trouble Installing rlang and TidyVerse

Tags: r, rstudio, rgui

I am using RGui 3.5.1 and RStudio 1.2.5. I am trying to load Tidyverse and it gave some error message about "onload failed in loadNameSpace() for 'rlang' " so I think maybe I need to load rlang first, but I got the same error message.

I have been going around the circle for days now, tried everything suggested online, except to uninstall the R studio as we need to go through IT for it (R is in local software center which we are able to download ourselves so I did uninstall R and install it myself but its still not working).

Following advice found online,

- I deleted rlang then checked on R:

  > library("rlang")
  >   Error in library("rlang") : there is no package called ‘rlang’
- Then I made sure the CRANExtra is removed

  > setRepositories()
- Then I specified the library location to install

  > install.packages("rlang",lib="C:/Users/LIN0001/DataNow/Home/R/win-library/3.5")
  >   trying URL 'https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2018-08-01/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/rlang_0.2.1.zip'
  >   Content type 'application/zip' length 821580 bytes (802 KB)
  >   downloaded 802 KB

  package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

  The downloaded binary packages are in
      C:\Users\LIN0001\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpigNMZO\downloaded_packages
  ---Then I try to load it from the same folder:

  > library("rlang",lib.loc="C:/Users/LIN0001/DataNow/Home/R/win-library/3.5")
  >   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rlang’:
  >   .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rlang', details:
  >   call: dots_list(...)
  >   error: object 'rlang_dots_list' not found

I also unticked the "use secure download method for http" of packages option in RStudio and when installing Tidyverse, I selected No instead of Yes on the pop up window (can't remember the exact message, something to do with security again); I have tried to load it both on R and Rstudio but got the same error messages.

Now I ran out of options to try so please help.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry not sure why the first couple of letters are missing. It should read: I am using RGui 3.5.1 and RStudio 1.2.5. Thanks

Comment: Is it on purpose, that you load rlang version 0.2.1? Currently it should be 0.4.2 https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rlang/index.html

Comment: @TobiO, that's the version that was available on Aug 1, 2018, as suggested by the `mran...snapshot...` in the URL. (Ref: https://github.com/r-lib/rlang/blob/d97e73d64a9392e887a5b67229b7d326c43fd3a7/DESCRIPTION)

Comment: @TobiO The version number was automatic loaded, How do I specify it

Comment: why are you using mran and not cran? What's your R version? I suggest you update your whole installation with `installr::updater()` running it from the command line (not R-studio). Perhaps you have to install the library `installr` before

Comment: If you would like to fully uninstall then reinstall R and RStudio, follow the steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61187094/1953250