# R studio not responding

Tags: r, rstudio

My RStudio is opening multiple processes(opening R Studio in different windows) when I open just one. I am not able to open any project. It becomes unresponsive. I tried using in compatibility mode, running as admin and also uninstalled. But still,[(here's the image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWufV.jpg) the same problem persists. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Sometimes it helps to reinstall R itself - often a hanging RStudio session is the result of a misconfigured or mislocated R executable.

Comment: Can you run R (without error) without RStudio? In the same directory? If the answers are "yes" then "no", perhaps something there is messing things up, perhaps `.Rprofile`, `.Renviron`, or `.Rdata` (though I don't know exactly what would cause that).

Comment: This might be worth an issue on https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues

Comment: I linked Rstudio with GitHub yesterday. Have I done something wrong there?

Comment: @r2evans I am able to run R without RStudio

Comment: If you would like to fully uninstall then reinstall R and RStudio, follow the steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61187094/1953250

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before you reinstall everything, which may take a lot of time, it is worth removing application data, which is a cache R keeps of last sessions etc. It involves settings such as information from last session, etc which RStudio tries to reopen every time you open it.

For app data, look under your user folder which must be somewhere like

```
c:\Users\<your_user_here\AppData\Local
c:\Users\<your_user_here\AppData\Local\LocalLow
c:\Users\<your_user_here\AppData\Roaming
```

Delete every subfolder called `R`, `RStudio-Desktop` or `RStudio` under these folders. Don't worry, you won't lose your source program files and projects. It may help you recover everything without having to start over from scratch.