# R filter function is returning a dataset full of NA values when run

Tags: r, filter, na

I have downloaded a dataset from https://www.kaggle.com/aungpyaeap/supermarket-sales

I am trying to filter the data on branch A to make a line graph for just branch A. When I run the code bellow the output is a lot of NA values. I have checked for NA and Null values in the dataset. Any help with how to filter on branch A correctly would be greatly appreciated.

head of the dataset -

```
`Invoice ID` Branch City      `Customer type` Gender `Product line`         `Unit price` Quantity `Tax 5%` Total Date       Time   Payment      cogs `gross margin percentage` `gross income` Rating
  <chr>        <chr>  <chr>     <chr>           <chr>  <chr>                         <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <date>     <time> <chr>       <dbl>                     <dbl>          <dbl>  <dbl>
1 750-67-8428  A      Yangon    Member          Female Health and beauty              74.7        7    26.1  549.  2019-01-05 13:08  Ewallet     523.                       4.76          26.1     9.1
2 226-31-3081  C      Naypyitaw Normal          Female Electronic accessories         15.3        5     3.82  80.2 2019-03-08 10:29  Cash         76.4                      4.76           3.82    9.6
3 631-41-3108  A      Yangon    Normal          Male   Home and lifestyle             46.3        7    16.2  341.  2019-03-03 13:23  Credit card 324.                       4.76          16.2     7.4
4 123-19-1176  A      Yangon    Member          Male   Health and beauty              58.2        8    23.3  489.  2019-01-27 20:33  Ewallet     466.                       4.76          23.3     8.4
5 373-73-7910  A      Yangon    Normal          Male   Sports and travel              86.3        7    30.2  634.  2019-02-08 10:37  Ewallet     604.                       4.76          30.2     5.3
6 699-14-3026  C      Naypyitaw Normal          Male   Electronic accessories         85.4        7    29.9  628.  2019-03-25 18:30  Ewallet     598.                       4.76          29.9     4.1
>
```

Code-

```
library(readr)
dataset <- read_csv("dataset.csv", 
                    col_types = cols(Date = col_date(format = "%m/%d/%Y"), 
                                     Time = col_time(format = "%H:%M")))
View(dataset)
df<- dataset

sum(is.na(df))
sum(is.null(df))

df_filter_A <- filter(df, Branch == "A")
head(df_filter_A)
```

Comment: The data cannot be downloaded without a kaggle account. Can you provide a (small) dataset that reproduces your problem? E.g. using dput() on a subset of the data.

Comment: I ran the very same code and had no problems, no NA values. Maybe check your dataset.csv file? Does it look ok? Does `dataset` look ok when you view it? Maybe replace `Branch=="A"` with `1==1` in your filter to see if that has anything to do with it. Try `read.csv` as well to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: @Laterow is that better?

Comment: @Brendan I have redownload the file but that did not work. Replacing Branch=="A" with 1==1 did not filter but I am not getting NA values anymore. What does this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled R and now the the code works as it should. I believe it was something to do with the libraries. I followed this post for uninstalling-

[How to uninstall R and RStudio with all packages, settings and everything else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55204017/how-to-uninstall-r-and-rstudio-with-all-packages-settings-and-everything-else).

Thank you for all the help and looking at my code.