# Error in sp::CRS(SRS_string = "EPSG:24547") : NA

Tags: r, r-sp, proj, proj4js

I am encountering an issue related to assigning CRS in sp package

If I run:

```
sp::CRS(SRS_string='EPSG:4326')

sp::CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
```

I get respectively those two errors:

> Error in sp::CRS(SRS_string = "EPSG:4326") : NA

> Error in sp::CRS("+init=epsg:4326") : NA

I checked whether rgdal uses the minimal PROJ/GDAL versions:

```
rgdal::rgdal_extSoftVersion()

GDAL GDAL_with_GEOS           PROJ             sp 

"3.2.1"         "TRUE"        "7.2.1"        "1.4-5"
```

And it also works if I use `proj4string` format to the `CRS()` function:

```
CRS("+proj=utm +zone=47 +a=6377304.063 +b=6356103.038993155 +towgs84=-11,851,5,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs")
```

But there is a warning message in `proj4string` format:

Warning message:

> In showSRID(uprojargs, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO", prefer_proj
> = prefer_proj) :  Discarded datum unknown in Proj4 definition

I have uninstalled R and RStudio with all packages, settings, and everything else using this guideline: [How to uninstall R and RStudio with all packages, settings and everything else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55204017/how-to-uninstall-r-and-rstudio-with-all-packages-settings-and-everything-else) , but the problem is not being solved when I reinstalled R,Rstudio as well ass the needed pacakges.

Comment: in my case a reinstallation of rdgal with ```install.packages("rgdal", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")``` and setting ```rgdal::set_proj_search_paths("C:/Users/Christof/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/rgdal/proj")``` as described here https://github.com/jhollist/elevatr/issues/48#issuecomment-1059802332 had fixed the same problem