# "Error in .Call(): Function not available for .Call() ..." when running third-party package

Tags: r, rcpp

I am trying to run the "[rrpack](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=rrpack)" under version 4.2.0 of R. However, there was a missing function which was not provided under Rcpp 1.0.6. so I updated it to Rcpp 1.0.8.3. As a result, I'm confronted with the following error message:

```
Error in .Call("_rrpack_lasso_shooting", PACKAGE = "rrpack", xtx, xty,  : "_rrpack_lasso_shooting" not available for .Call() for package "rrpack"
```

I found several threads describing this error message but only in the context of package development. Usual solutions are, for example, missing `dynLib(packagename)` in the `NAMEFILE` but the `roxygen2` generated document looks fine so I ended up without any suggestions applicable to my case. The CRAN checks for rrpack are all "OK" so I am very unsure if this is a simple issue that can be fixed from my side or something else.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your OS? How did you install `rrpack`?  Did you also update `Rcpp` (as the mismatch between the one you run and that `rrpack` was built against is your local source of error as per many earlier threads here).  With consistent compilation of both all should work as you see at CRAN:  https://cloud.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_rrpack.html

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I'm working on Windows 11. I completely uninstalled R + RStudio and removed all packages according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55204017/how-to-uninstall-r-and-rstudio-with-all-packages-settings-and-everything-else) guide. Then I reinstalled rrpack, Rcpp and all other necessary packages through the RStudio console. However, the error remains, that's why I decided to pose the question. I would be really grateful if you could specify on the "mismatch" you mention as I don't fully grasp th error yet @Dirk Eddelbuettel

Comment: Hm, that has me stumped. You did more cleanup than needed.  This should work, as it does for CRAN.

Answer (score 0):

This may be of little comfort to you but I just installed `rrpack` (along with its dependencies) into a fresh Docker session and all is well (see below).  So we need more info from you about "how" you do things as something went south for you.

```
root@10e3fc571ea5:/# R     

R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22) -- "Vigorous Calisthenics" 
Copyright (C) 2022 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing 
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)   

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors. 
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.
> library(rrpack)
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.10.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.10.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices datasets  utils     methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rrpack_0.1-12

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.8.3     magrittr_2.0.3   splines_4.2.0    MASS_7.3-57     
 [5] munsell_0.5.0    colorspace_2.0-3 lattice_0.20-45  R6_2.5.1        
 [9] rlang_1.0.2      foreach_1.5.2    fansi_1.0.3      grid_4.2.0      
[13] glmnet_4.1-4     gtable_0.3.0     utf8_1.2.2       cli_3.3.0       
[17] iterators_1.0.14 ellipsis_0.3.2   survival_3.3-1   tibble_3.1.7    
[21] lifecycle_1.0.1  crayon_1.5.1     Matrix_1.4-1     ggplot2_3.3.6   
[25] vctrs_0.4.1      codetools_0.2-18 shape_1.4.6      bspm_0.3.9      
[29] glue_1.6.2       compiler_4.2.0   pillar_1.7.0     scales_1.2.0    
[33] pkgconfig_2.0.3 
>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and generous help! I was able to avoid the error through tedious trial and error, but I am not completely satisfied because I still don't understand the source of the problem. Specifically, I added optional inputs for the 
 `control` argument (list of internal computation parameters controlling optimization) of the `sofar` function in `rrpack` which somewhat solves the error. As the inputs are optional (i.e. the documentation example doesn't use them), I am still puzzled but error free.

Answer (score 0):

The "rrpack" author just updated the "rrpack" package that has fixed this issue.

Comment: It might be helpful to list the new specific rrpack version you're referring to. There could be a subsequent version that causes another issue and that info would be helpful.