# could not find function "p" error after reinstalling & updating R and all packages

Tags: r

I know this is the sort of question that is hated in any forum, but I have tried my best: I could not get rid of the error below, so I ended up [taking the suggested steps for this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027288/error-could-not-find-function-in-r), [de- and reinstalled R and all packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55204017/how-to-uninstall-r-and-rstudio-with-all-packages-settings-and-everything-else), and it worked! For a short time - now, after having restarted my computer, I receive the same familiar error from a function that I do not directly call and which I find hard to trace ("p"?). As far as I know, the functions I call are not deprecated - it did end up working after cleaning my computer of everything related to R. In addition to de-/reinstalling R, is there a good tip of how to deal with such an issue? Is there a particular information from my system that could help trace this error?

This is my rather simple code which is supposed to set NA's to the maximum value in each pid-group:

```
require("tidyverse")

list_na <- c("val1","val2")
dftest <- data.frame(pid=c(rep(1,5),rep(0,5)),
                     val1=c(NA,1,1,1,3,NA,NA,3,1,NA),
                     val2=c(NA,1,1,1,3,NA,NA,3,-100,NA))
dftest <- dftest %>% group_by(pid) %>%
  mutate(across(any_of(list_na), ~replace_na(.x, max(.x, na.rm = T))))
dftest
```

Error message:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = across(any_of(list_na), ~replace_na(.x,
max(.x, na.rm =   TRUE)))`. Caused by error in `across()`: 
! Problem while computing column `val1`. Caused by error in `p()`: 
! could not find function "p"
```

I have no idea what p() refers to.

Comment: I get a different error when I run your code: "could not find function "any_off". It should be `any_of`, not `any_off`. Maybe it depends on your dplyr version what message you get.

Comment: ah sorry, it should be any_of, I added this part manually to the code to after I copied it over - the error message is not affected by this, there is just an additional message that tells me to use any_of / all_of. All of my packages are updated to the most current version

Comment: Please edit your question to show exactly what you are running. If I change `any_off` to `any_of` myself, your code runs just fine without errors. Test with `dplyr_1.0.10`.

Comment: any_of() <https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RVerbalExpressions/versions/0.0.0.9000/topics/any_of> Get no error!

Comment: Another vote for "runs without error after correcting `any_of`" (also dplyr 1.0.10)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! There seems to have been a problem with the packages I had loaded in the background, probably a function defined multiple times which I did not include in my coding sample.

This works:

```
dftest <- dftest %>%  group_by(pid) %>%
        dplyr::mutate(dplyr::across(dplyr::any_of(list_na), ~tidyr::replace_na(.x, max(.x, na.rm = T))))
```