# quarto shiny documents render fine in RStudio viewer, but not as .html

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, quarto

Ran into an issue where I'm trying to create a standalone interactive quarto document using rshiny. I've created many quarto documents before, so I know it can be kind of temperamental, but when I follow the basic introductory quarto documentation for creating a shiny doc (https://quarto.org/docs/interactive/shiny/), I've been running into some weird issues. The viewer pane in RStudio produces exactly the expected output[image: RStudio viewer output], but when I open the .html file to view in a browser, none of the plots or interactable elements load properly. The slider is replaced with a generic input box, and the figures are just missing entirely.  [image: broken .html file output]

I've tried updating quarto, then R, then RStudio. I even tried uninstalling R, quarto, RStudio, then wiping ALL R files from my computer by manually deleting everything found in .libPaths() and/or that even mention R ([How to uninstall R and RStudio with all packages, settings and everything else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55204017/how-to-uninstall-r-and-rstudio-with-all-packages-settings-and-everything-else)). After I reinstalled everything I'm still getting the same issue.

I've tried opening the .html fil in three different browsers and on four different Operating Systems, and still nothing. This tells me that it's a problem with how the actual file is being generated and not how it's being interpreted/rendered.

At this point, I have no idea what to try to make this render properly.

If it helps, I'm using the most recent versions of R (4.3.3) and RStudio (2023.12.1-402) on a Windows 11 device.

Comment: You cannot create an shiny server site that runs in a stand alone mode. When using shiny and R, you need an active R processes to run all the interactive commands. There is an extension like [shinylive](https://quarto.org/docs/blog/posts/2022-10-25-shinylive-extension/) which can compile code into WASM to run in the browser without R, but for now I think that's still limited to the python version of shiny, not the R version.

Comment: Actually the R version does have some mention of using it with quarto. I've not tried it myself but checkout https://github.com/posit-dev/r-shinylive/

Comment: That's a real bummer. The documentation that I was able to find wasn't clear to me that that was the case. r-shinylive seems like a really cool workaround, and I'll have to look more into it. Thanks!